# How does TypeScript know that this union type of tuple types is equivalent to a tuple type of unions?

Tags: typescript

How does TypeScript know that this union type of tuple types is equivalent to a tuple type of unions?

```
type LHS = ['a' | 'b', 'b'];
type RHS = ['a', 'b'] | ['b', 'b']

type Equiv<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? true : never : never;

const x: Equiv<LHS, RHS> = true; // ok
```

I'm asking because this is given as an example in ["Advanced Logical Type Systems for Logical Languages"](https://pnwamk.github.io/docs/dissertation.pdf). (`(α∪β)×β <: (α×β)∪(β×β)` , on page 4) where the author argues that it's hard to cases like this right with just syntactic rules, then goes on to show a "semantic" approach.

What I'm looking for is whether TS does a trick like converting to disjunctive normal form before comparing, or does TS just have really thorough typing rules? Based on what I know from last playing with the internals, I strongly suspect the latter, but want to double-check.

Comment: Eh I think you’re just getting distributive conditional types where you don’t want them, and `true | never` Is just `true`